# How to count the total keys in an array based on the value of that key

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

This might be a basic question, but I am not getting any efficient way to do this. Suppose I have an array of multiple objects containing multiple key value like this. Now, I want the total count of `grActual` whose value is 16- Jan-13.I can iterate the array, and create a new array with key `grAcutal` and then I can count. Is there any other way to do that?

```
    (
    {
    gIActual = "17-Jan-13";
    grActual = "16-Jan-13";
},
    {
    gIActual = "18-Jan-13";
    grActual = "16-Jan-13";
},
    {
    gIActual = "16-Jan-13";
    grActual = "16-Jan-13";      
},
    {
    gIActual = "16-Feb-13";
    grActual = "16-Jan-13";
})
```

Comment: You can use Predicate to search objects like `NSArray *filteredarray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(grActual == %@)", @"16- Jan-13"]];` which will give you number of objects in the array, the total count of the array would be the Count you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this will do it, not that I use `NSPredicate` very often:

```
NSArray *filtered = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"grActual == %@", @"16-Jan-13"]];
NSUInteger count = [filtered count];
```

Tip: Store data using the correct type, which for `16-Jan-13` is `NSDate`, not `NSString` (not to mention Y2K and localization issues...).

Comment: It can be searched with `NSString` using `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(grActual == %@)", @"16-Jan-13"]`

Comment: you can't assign in a predicate and the brackets are meaningless in this case so the original was simpler and also correct...

Comment: @Wain Yes brackets are meaningless, you can assign using `==` and it works too.

Comment: @Wain Thanks.  As you can see I don't use `NSPredicate` often enough (I am happy with filtering by block, which can do anything).